# Plastic fitting cracked in kitchen faucet supply line

Tags: plumbing, rubber

[image: This fitting]

The fitting is cracked along its base as you can see in the picture.  This is the faucet-end of a quick connect fitting (the other side goes to the spray hose).  I'm hoping to not have to replace the entire line.  Is there a way to repair the split?  Or cut the tubing and replace the fitting itself?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is that you're best replacing the line, as a reliable fix will be tough. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried heat-shrink tubing: no way, not enough of a seal for the pressure.  I tried electrical tape: much better, but could not withstand the 30 psi max pressure of a supply tube.

The tube itself is, unfortunately, part of the faucet assembly, so I was forced to replace the entire faucet.  I notice that Pfister now uses a different fitting for the quick connect joint, no doubt because the one depicted above was breaking in the field.

So the best answer seems to be, sadly, to replace the entire faucet assembly.